# Convert Scala Reflection MethodMirror to Scala Function

Tags: scala, reflection

I am trying to create a Seq of methods that will operate on a Spark DataFrame. Currently I am explicitly creating this Seq at runtime:

```
val allFuncs: Seq[DataFrame => DataFrame] = Seq(func1, func2, func3)
def func1(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {}
def func2(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {}
def func3(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {}
```

I added functionality that allows developers to add an annotation and I'm creating a Seq of MethodMirrors from it like so, but I'd like `getMyFuncs` to return a `Seq[(DataFrame => DataFrame)]`:

```
  def getMyFuncs(): Seq[(DataFrame => DataFrame)] = {
    // Gets anything with the @MyFunc annotation
    val listOfAnnotations = typeOf[T].members.flatMap(f => f.annotations.find(_.tree.tpe =:= typeOf[MyFunc]).map((f, _))).toList
    val rm = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
    val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(this)
    listOfAnnotations.map(annotation =>   instanceMirror.reflectMethod(annotation._1.asMethod)).toSeq
}

@MyFunc
def func1(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {}
@MyFunc
def func2(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {}
@MyFunc
def func3(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {}
```

However, the Seq returned by `getMyFuncs` is a `Seq[reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror]`, not `Seq[(DataFrame => DataFrame)]`. Which is expected, but not the output I need. Is there any way to convert the MethodMirrors into a Scala function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mapping:

```
val getMyFuncs: Seq[reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror] = ???
val getMyFuncs1: Seq[DataFrame => DataFrame] = 
  getMyFuncs.map(mirror => (dataFrame: DataFrame) => mirror(dataFrame).asInstanceOf[DataFrame])
```

i.e. creating lambdas manually using [`reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror#apply(..)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Mirrors.scala#L390-L396).

Comment: Wow, short and sweet. This makes sense to me. It's very close to what I had to solve this before you answered. Thank you for your help @Dmytro!