# How to generate Function1 by parameter Class and return Class

Tags: scala, reflect

I want to register a scala Object Method into spark udf. Now i get the MethodMirror by scala reflect and Parameter by java reflect. But i cannot generate a Function object used to register into spark.udf. Such as:

```
object ArrayUdfs {
  def array2String(arr: Seq[Long])= {
    arr.mkString(",")
  }
}
```

I want to register method 'array2String' into spark udf.

First i get the MethodMirror:

```
def getObjectMethod(clazzPath:String, methodName:String)  = {
   import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

   lazy val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
   lazy val module = runtimeMirror.staticModule(clazzPath)
   lazy val obj = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(module)
   lazy val objMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(obj.instance)
   lazy val method = obj.symbol.typeSignature.member(universe.TermName(methodName)).asMethod
   lazy val methodObject = objMirror.reflectMethod(method)
   methodObject
}

lazy val method = getObjectMethod(clazzPath, funName);
```

Second. I get Parameter.

```
def getObjectMethodParams(clazzPath:String, methodName:String): Array[Parameter] = {
    val methods = Class.forName(clazzPath).getDeclaredMethods()
    var params: Array[Parameter] = null;
    methods.foreach(method => {
      if (method.getName == methodName) params = method.getParameters
    })
    params
}

val params = getObjectMethodParams(clazzPath, funName)
```

Third, register it into spark.udf

```
val function1: Function1[Seq[String], String] = (arr) => {
   method.apply(arr).asInstanceOf[String]
}

spark.udf.register("array2String", function1)
```

So i want to replace 'Seq[String]' in 'Function1[Seq[String], String]' by 'params' object. The 'String' in 'Function1[Seq[String], String]' is same.

Comment: I guess mixing Scala reflection and Java reflection is a bad idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463273/convert-scala-reflection-methodmirror-to-scala-function

Comment: Thanks. It is sloved by use 'Any' repalce 'Seq[String]' and 'String'. I use java reflection becase i cannpt get param list from scala reflection.